# Null Pointer Exception error Jframe windowbuilder

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, windowbuilder

Here is the SSCCEE

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at PotterMCSR.test(PotterMCSR.java:1786)
   at PotterMCSR.jbInit(PotterMCSR.java:452)
at PotterMCSR.<init>(PotterMCSR.java:448)
at PotterMCSR$1.run(PotterMCSR.java:343)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm trying to parse a double from an object using getValue() in order to add a bunch of values from different text fields and send that total to a different text field. I think it is because when it tries to parse the getValue() it is null.

```
    protected void do_ftfIncomeSalary_propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
     Double salary = ((double)((ftfIncomeSalary.getValue())));
     Double CurrTotalIncome = ((double)((ftfTotalIncome.getValue())));
     Double totalIncome= salary+CurrTotalIncome;
     ftfIncomeSalary.setValue(totalIncome);
}
```

Comment: can you show the code sippet

Comment: Where is the SSCCE? All you've posted is a stack trace.

Comment: sorry I'm new I thought that was the SSCCE